# Looking for example of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $\lim \inf E[X_n] \le E[\lim \inf X_n]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am looking for an example of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $\lim \inf E[X_n] \le E[\lim \inf X_n]$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Your textbook has **Fatou's lemma**, presumably.  And there may be some examples that go with it.

Comment: What @GEdgar said. And $X_n=0$ almost surely, for every $n$.

Comment: Since it is easy to get an example with ${}={}$, I am guessing Saun is more interested in an example with ${}<{}$.  This is where any text discussing Fatou's lemma will be useful.

Comment: This is NOT Fatou's lemma. It's the reverse inequality. This shows why Fatou's lemma needs the non-negativity criterion.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_n=-n^21_{[0,\frac{1}{n^2}]}$ independent then $EX_n=-1$ for every $n$. By Borel Cantelli, $X_n\to0$ a.e. Thus $E(\liminf X_n)=E(0)=0$ so here $-1=\liminf E(X_n)\leq E(\liminf X_n)=0$.

This shows why Fatou's Lemma needs the non-negativity criterion. The usual Fatou's lemma is for $X_n\geq0$, $E(\liminf X_n)\leq \liminf E(X_n)$.